# How to remove gems from RVM Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to remove all my gems on my rails app, because i know some gems aren't used for my app.

From terminal:

```
gem list
```

how to remove those gem from my gem list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rvm, type this from your terminal:

```
rvm gemset empty
```

Comment: Thanks, now i can install gems with new Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

`gem uninstall yourgem`. `gem --help` has more in store for you

Comment: this only remove 1 gem from my gem list, i want remove all gems

Comment: my apologies, I did not paid enough attention.